# TikZ macro for mathematical operation

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, macros

I have the following code

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0.2in,%
left=0.5in,right=0.5in,top=1in,bottom=1in,%
footskip=.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows,arrows.meta,shapes,tikzmark,decorations.markings,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,breaklinks,plainpages=false,linkcolor=blue!50!black,urlcolor=blue!50!black,citecolor=blue!50!black,bookmarks=true,bookmarksopenlevel=2]{hyperref}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\cfoot{\thepage}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\pagestyle{empty}

\begingroup
\addtolength{\jot}{1em}
\[
\begin{aligned}
&\quad\left(
\tikz[baseline,remember picture]{\node[fill=green!20,anchor=base] (t1){$ AX $};}\pm
\tikz[baseline,remember picture]{\node[fill=blue!20,anchor=base] (t2){$ CY $};}\right)\left(
\tikz[baseline,remember picture]{\node[fill=cyan!20,anchor=base] (n1){$ EW $};}\pm
\tikz[baseline,remember picture]{\node[fill=magenta!20,anchor=base] (n2){$ GZ $};}\right)\\
\end{aligned}
\]
\endgroup

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay] %% use here too
\draw[green,thick,->] (t1.north) to [bend left] (n1.north);
\draw[green,thick,->] (t1.north) to [bend left] (n2.north);
\draw[blue,thick,->] (t2.south) to [bend right] (n2.south);
\draw[blue,thick,->] (t2.south) to [bend right] (n1.south);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

That output is ok to show the distributive property between two binomials. Now, I want to know if it would be possible to create a macro to achieve a similar output no matter how many terms are involved in the expression, i.e. monomial, binomials, trinomials, etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm quite convinced that such a diagram only confuses the minds of the young kids.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> [image]
>
> *This answer contains explicit results and should not be shown to kids (as mentioned by @egreg in his comment).*

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{
  from/.style={fill={red!\col!blue}},
  to/.style={fill={green!\col!red}},
  symb/.style={inner sep=0},
  node distance=2pt
}
% --------------------
\def\froms{A,B,C}
\def\tos{D,...,G}
% --------------------
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    % -------- FIRST PART
    \path
      foreach[
        count=\i,
        remember=\i as \j (initially 0),
        evaluate={\col=30*\i}
      ] \from in \froms{
        \ifnum \i > 1
          node[right=of F\j,symb] (O){$\pm$}
        \else
          node[symb](O){$($}
        \fi
        node[right=of O,from] (F\i){$\from$}
      }
      \pgfextra{\xdef\numfrom{\j}}
    ;
    % -------- SECOND PART
    \path
      foreach[
        count=\i,
        remember=\i as \j (initially 0),
        evaluate={\col=20*\i}
      ] \from in \tos{
        \ifnum \i > 1
          node[right=of T\j,symb] (O){$\pm$}
        \else
          node[right=of F\numfrom,symb](O){$)($}
        \fi
        node[right=of O,to] (T\i){$\from$}
      }
      node[right=of T\j,symb] (O){$)$}
      \pgfextra{\xdef\numto{\j}}
    ;
    % -------- ARROWS PART
    \foreach[evaluate={\coli=30*\i}] \i in {1,...,\numfrom}
      \foreach[evaluate={\colj=15*\j}] \j in {1,...,\numto}
      \path ([xshift=\numto pt-2*\j pt]F\i.north) edge[draw={green!\colj!red!\coli!blue},out=30+10*\j,in=130-5*\i,-latex] ([xshift=3*\i pt-1.5*\numfrom pt]T\j.north);

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: a 3D rendering, with arrows from A on top, from B on bottom, from C on the side, would be so much more pedagogical !

Comment: Hello @Kpym, thanks for your help. I was trying to edit the code in order to control the signs between the terms. I created \def\fsigns{+,-} for the first part and \def\tsigns{-,+,-} for the second but the implementation is producing an error. How could I implement this correctly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 for "parental advisory"

Comment: @MathTeX if you want `+,-,+,-,...` you can make a parity check and then display one or the other. If you want more complicated sequence you can use a pgf array, for example `\def\tsigns{{"-","+","-"}}`, and then evaluate it at some index, for example`\tsigns[2]` *(check [this answer](/a/227516))*.

Comment: @Kpym, thanks again for your help, that solved my issue.